# Find Match and Replace using Sublime or Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

the title says pretty much what im trying to achieve, i have a list with around 3,000 lots, this lots get sold at random, here is how the lots list look like:

[image: image example]

On row A i have a list of available lots, on row B i have a list of lots that have been sold from list A.

The lots that have been sold are random and they can be find on row A.

what im trying to do here is, Find and match the lots from row B to Row A and Replace just the value -1 to -0........ -1 means available and -0 means sold.

i can do this by trying to find each lot on row A one by one, but the problem here is that the list on row A is around 3,000 and the list on row B, the sold list, is around 1,000 and keeps growing little by little witch makes the task of finding and matching one by one a tedious job.

I currently have sublime and use google sheets, my knowledge on google sheets is limited and on sublime im not very familiar with regex. whichever is easier, i will greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, NOT(COUNTIF(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "(.+)-0$")&"-1", A2:A)))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+)-1$")&"-0", 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, B2:B)&"$"), A2:A))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thankyou so much, i really need to practice formulas, you are a life saver.

Comment: Is this learned on basic or advanced regex?

Comment: I would say its a basic regex